# How can I take text and convert to PDF with landscape orientation and two text columns?

Tags: itext, itext7

I need to change the paper orientation, and then divide the text into two columns. I want like it:

[image]

I come from a large text file and I need to add all of this text in the PDF as in the photo.

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
PageSize ps = PageSize.A4;;
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, ps);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("verybigfileWithText.txt"));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
//split pdf and add text in two column without overlapping page
}
doc.close();
```

And I need to be able to change margin in center(between two columns) and margin top/right/bot/left. And get width every columns :)

Help me please
Pdf:
https://dropmefiles.com/HqD6f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the orientation of the page you can use `PageSize#rotate`, e.g. `PageSize.A4.rotate()`

To put content into two (or more) columns, you can create your own document renderer, or use an existing `ColumnDocumentRenderer` which suits your needs. It accepts column areas which allows you to control margins (or even position columns in a peculiar way which is probably not your use case):

```
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4.rotate());
Rectangle[] columnAreas = new Rectangle[] {new Rectangle(30, 30, 350, 520), new Rectangle(430, 30, 350, 520)};
ColumnDocumentRenderer renderer = new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columnAreas);
document.setRenderer(renderer);

document.add(new Paragraph(text).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED));

document.close();
```

The result looks like this:
[image: result]